# Can I alternate between “you” and “us” when writing wishes in a greeting card?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, sentence-construction

I’d like to write something like this: “May the charms of Christmas gladden YOUR heart and lighten YOUR burdens. May the spirit inspire US to bring healing and hopes to the world.”
I wonder if it’s natural to use “your” in the first part and “us” in the second part.

Comment: What are your specific doubts about these sentences?  What makes you think using *your* and *us* might be a problem?

Comment: I thought they’d sound unnatural or inconsistent. I could’ve said “may the charms of Christmas gladden our hearts and lighten our burdens”, but it sounds less nice though I’m not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. The pronoun should indicate who is being addressed or discussed. If the subject changes, then the pronoun should change.

The question is whether the pronouns in each sentence are appropriate. In your example, I think they clearly are. Your first sentence is wishing a benefit. Your second sentence is calling for a response. It could seem selfish to wish a benefit on yourself, so it's quite appropriate to make the subject of the benefit "you". But it could seem lazy to call for the other person to take some action while not including yourself, like you're going to sit on the couch and watch TV while they do all the work. So it makes sense for that sentence to say "us".

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, there is no problem.

Your first sentence is addressed to a third party or parties.

Your second sentence carries the sense of **inspire us all**. That implies you, the person/s addressed and people in general.

It would sound strange if you addressed the second sentence to **you** unless you were directing this message to hugely influential or inspirational people who might indeed achieve such ends.

So yes, it's fine.